# Java LWJGL - Monster follow script not working properly

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl

I have written a script to be set off whenever a player is within a distance of the monster. The script checks if the x position is greater than or less than the players x, and same for the z. (y is automatically set to terrain) The checkWalkX and checkWalkZ functions work with my monsters walk function, which specifies a new position on a timer and walks to that position. But when I use the same kind of idea for the following, it doesnt work correctly.

```
public int checkWalkX(Vector3f position) {
    if (Math.floor(this.getX()) != Math.floor(position.x)) {
        if(this.getX() > position.x) return 1; //Greater
        if(this.getX() < position.x) return 2; //Less
    } 
    return 0;
}
public int checkWalkZ(Vector3f position) {
    if (Math.floor(this.getZ()) != Math.floor(position.z)) {
        if(this.getZ() > position.z) return 1; //Greater
        if(this.getZ() < position.z) return 2; //Less
    } 
    return 0;
}

public void follow(Player player) {
    walking = false;
    following = true;

    if(checkWalkX(player.getPosition()) == 1) this.setX(this.getX() - mobSpeed);
    else if(checkWalkX(player.getPosition()) == 2) this.setX(this.getX() + mobSpeed);

    if(checkWalkZ(player.getPosition()) == 1) this.setZ(this.getZ() - mobSpeed);
    else if(checkWalkZ(player.getPosition()) == 2) this.setZ(this.getZ() + mobSpeed);

    if(Math.floor(checkWalkX(walkToPosition)) == 0 && Math.floor(checkWalkZ(walkToPosition)) == 0) following = false;
}
```

For some reason when I run this script, the monster will only move within a distance of 2ish. He moves the right ways kinda, but he doesnt follow me. Would anyone know why this is?

Comment: Why are you using `Math.floor()`? Why in the last line of `follow()`? There it is not necessary since you only return `0`, `1` or `2`.

Comment: What is the unit of mobSpeed? Way per timestep?

Comment: If I didnt floor it would always be off by .000* whatever and the monster jerks side to side

Comment: mobspeed is the amount to move each render

Comment: So you Limit the position to be at whole numbers? 1 2 3.., no 1.3674? You then really should use an int based vector.

Comment: The monster moves by a float, but the positions are rarely to the exact decimal place as the player, thats why i floor it

Comment: Makes sense in my mind unless its doing something different

Comment: It makes sense but not in the last line and only if you compare with doubles as well. `CheckWalkX()` only returns whole numbers [0,1,2] as ints. `Math.floor() converts it to doubles e.g. `0.99999999*` which you then compares to an int `0`.

Comment: I thought math.floor strips off the characters after the decimal though? But I understand what your saying

Comment: You can cast the double values to integers instead: int foo = (int) myDoubleBar;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want you to think about a refactoring of your code. Since you already have a vector structure (Vector3f - I guess its from lwjgl) why not use it?

```
// Calculate the vector pointing from the mob toward the position with
// a length of their distance.
// This is equal to: wayTowardPlayer = playerPosition - mobPosition
Vector3f wayTowardPlayer = new Vector3f();
Vector3f.sub(player.getPosition(), this.position, wayTowardPlayer);

// Check if both are not at the same position, yet.
if (wayTowardPlayer.lengthSquared() > 0) {

    // Here you also could:
    // - Clamp your vector to let the mob not walk more than some pixels,
    //    regardless of its distance to the player.
    // - Scale it by e.g. 0.5 let the mob walk only half the way toward player.
    // - Clamp it to [-1,0,+1] so it reflects the direction you want to move
    //   and then multiply it with a velocity and passed time since last update
    //   to let it move smoothly toward the player over time without jumping.

    // Add the calculated vector to the mobs postion.
    // If you didn't manipulate it as described before it's position then
    // is that of the player.
    // This is equal to: mobPosition = playerPosition + wayTowardPlayer
    add(this.position, wayTowardPlayer, this.position);
}
```

I also recommend you to quit with using lwjgl `Vector3f` since it only has static members for addition and substraction. What about using those classes from [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector3.html)? Libgdx uses LWJGL for desktop rendering as well and has a lot of tools integrated that makes programming easier. It also allows to easy build portable apps for different plattforms, e.g. Android. In my games I always seperate game logic from graphics.

With libgdxs vector classes the last addition would simply be:

```
this.position.add(wayTowardPlayer);
```

Comment: I just have a question about this.. Where does it calculate the "speed" or how far to move each direction? What is the 'add(this.position, wayTowardPlayer, this.position);' ?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: You may find [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/93029/42954) post informative, too.