# Simple LibGDX Pong game drag player instead of getting x position

Tags: java, libgdx, touch

I got a working pong game in LibGDX but when I touch the screen the player x automaticly jumps to the coordinates I touched. I wan't my game to detect I touched and then move the player to the left/right if I swipe my finger to the left or the right.

This is what I tried so far:

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched() && Gdx.input.getY()>240*screenheight){
  if(tapped)TouchX = Gdx.input.getX();
    tapped = false;
    DragX = Gdx.input.getX();

    distance = player.getX() - TouchX;

    PlayerX = Gdx.input.getX() + distance;


    Gdx.app.log("PlayerX "+player.getX(), "Distance "+distance);
    Gdx.app.log("DragX ", ""+DragX);
}else{
    tapped = true;
}
```

Here I update the player X coordinates

```
player.setX(PlayerX);
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use InputAdapter class and methods

```
touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
Called when the screen was touched or a mouse button was pressed.

boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer)
Called when a finger or the mouse was dragged.

boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
Called when a finger was lifted or a mouse button was released.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could update the position over time:

```
currentPos = currentPos + Math.signum(currentPos - touchedPos) * wayPerTime * deltaTime;
```

- `wayPerTimestep` is your velocity.
- `deltaTime` is the time passed since the last update.
- `currentPos` is the current position of your player (might be `x`, `y` or both as vector).
- `touchedPos` is the position the player has clicked on the screen (might be `x`, `y` or both as vector).

`Math.signum()` gives you `+1` if the value is positive or `-1` if negative. Otherwise `0`. This takes care about the same speed regardless how big the distance is between player and clicked position.

The code uses this formula for calculating the way ***s***:

[image: Way is speed times time]

Comment: I can't figure out your solution It ends up with making the player x going down each gameloop by 1 I updated my question with what I tried so far can you maybe take a look at that?

Comment: This is because you don't incorporate the time and velocity. You implemented only the half of the equation. Use `Math.signum()` to figure out the direction to move. Then multiply it with the unsigned way you want to move to correct the position. If `currentpos - touchedPos` is `0` the result of `Math.signum` is `0` as well and so is the absolute way you add to the current position: The player doesn't move any longer.

Comment: Allright how do I exactly get the velocity? I'm not using dx for the player for its speed just the coordinates the mouse is currently at.

Comment: You have to design it by yourself. For example you could say the player moves within one second for `50px`. If you have the delta time (in seconds) passed since your last update you can simply multiply it with that value: `x += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTimer() * velocity`

Comment: Did it help? Anything you don't understand yet?